# Place a function at very start of binary

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm working on a toy operating system and bootloader. I'm trying to write the kernel in C, and then convert it to binary for direct jumping to from the bootloader (i.e., I'm not loading an ELF or anything like that).

I've got the linker file setup with the proper origin (I'm loading the kernel to address 0xC0000000) and confirm with `objdump` that it's using it correctly. However, it's not placing my entry point at the start (0xC0000000) like I wanted. I guess that's not what the `ENTRY` directive is for.

My problem is simply that I want to place a particular function, `kernel_main` at address 0xC0000000. Is there a way I can accomplish this using gcc for compiling and linking?

Here is what the relevant parts of my linker file look like:

```
ENTRY(kernel_main)

SECTIONS
{
   /* Origin */
   . = 0xC0000000;

   .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
   {
       *(.text)
   }
   /* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ENTRY` directive is only useful for output formats that support an entrypoint. Since you're using a binary output, this won't work. What you can do is write a small stub in a separate source file (i.e. `entry.c` or `entry.asm` or whatever). Then, in the `ld` script, before the `*(.text)` line, you can put `entry.o(.text)`. This instructs `ld` to load the symbols from a specific object file (whereas `*` denotes all object files). So the new `ld` script would look like this:
    ENTRY(kernel_main)

```
SECTIONS
{
   /* Origin */
  . = 0xC0000000;

   .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
   {
       entry.o(.text)
       *(.text)
   }
   /* etc. */
}
```

As long as `entry.o` contains just one function (that simply calls your kernel main), this should work.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I tested this out and it appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 4):

The `ENTRY` linker command tells the linker which symbol the loader should jump to when it loads the program. If you're making your own operating system it's really not used since there is no loader.

Instead, as you know, the program simply starts at the first code address.

To make place a special segment of code first, you could place it in a special code segment, and put it first in the list:

```
.text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(.text.boot) *(.text)
}
```

The segments in the list is placed in the order they are given.

Comment: Thanks that's a good solution. I tested it out and it works fine. The only reason I chose Drew's answer instead if because this relies on compiler specific syntax for assigning a function to a segment. Drew's answer is a little more generic and clean in my opinion, but both appear to work fine.